# angular2 quick start only showing Loading .. not the content of index.html

Tags: node.js, angular

for the first time using angular2 , following the instruction from [5 minute Quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#) for angular 2.

everything is working good, means no error while run `npm start`

[npm start image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Pq7.png)

but when i open

> localhost:3000

it show ***Loading...*** text which is not expecting. according to this example content of index.html should reflects on this.

in console there is error :

**EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property 'endSourceSpan' of null**

#### main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 'My first Angular 2 App</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me what is going wrong.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your main component? Thanks!

Comment: [code of main.ts](http://pastebin.com/xmsf94yi) << it's completely taken from the guide

Comment: okay, thanks! And the `app.component.ts` file?

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37070952/1961059 (incorrectly closed tags/typos, too)

Comment: i have added the code in Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you have a problem in the template of your main component. For example a HTML element that isn't correctly closed:

```
template : '<div</div>'
```

See this issue for more details:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7849

**Edit**

The problem is that your `h1` isn't correct (no begin element):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>' // <------
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. but there is no div  in template as you can see

Comment: yes.` h1` tag is not opened.  Thanks a lot man. Why angular 2 give strange error or I am unable to debug the error correctly.

Comment: You're welcome! I think that the Angular team works hard to improve this ;-)

Comment: one more query out of this question context. I have installed `typings` without `-g` now if I want to make it globally than do I need to remove earlier or any work around for this to make package globally.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the port number of nodeserver shows in your terminal,
In Angular2 it'll be running in 4200.
ie ** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **
Then open localhost with specified port in browser.