# Angular2-quickstart not loading, no errors

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

I followed [Angular.io's typescript](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files) tutorial to the T - all code is the same as shown at the bottom, as well as the file structure.

When I start the server, with `npm start`, the log shows:

```
 tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

  [0]
  [0] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc:w /Users/jr/angular2-quickstart
  [0] > tsc -w
  [0]
  [1]
  [1] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite /Users/jr/angular2-quickstart
  [1] > lite-server
  [1]
  [1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using  lite-   server defaults...
  [1] ** browser-sync config **
  [1] { injectChanges: false,
  [1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
  [1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
  [1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
  [1] [BS] Access URLs:
  [1]  --------------------------------------
  [1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
  [1]     External: http://192.168.0.181:3000
  [1]  --------------------------------------
  [1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
  [1]  UI External: http://192.168.0.181:3001
  [1]  --------------------------------------
  [1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
  [1] [BS] Watching files...
  [0] 10:21:10 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
  [1] [BS] File changed: app/app.component.js
  [1] [BS] File changed: app/main.js
```

The html page shows nothing, and the console gives a 500 internal error. When doing NPM install there were no errors at the bottom, but when I do npm ls, I get:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2, required by angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.12
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.2, required by angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.12
npm ERR! peer dep missing: reflect-metadata@0.1.2, required by angular2@2.0.0-beta.17
npm ERR! peer dep missing: es6-shim@^0.35.0, required by angular2@2.0.0-beta.17
npm ERR! extraneous: angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 /Users/jr/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/angular2
```

I've been chasing my own tail for the past couple of hours trying to install dependencies, deleteing the node_module folder, and doing npm cache clean.

Much love if you can lend a hand

Edit: Using NPM 3.10.2 and Node 6.2.2

EDIT2: Tried the above steps on a different machine, and it worked. Will update back on results from debugging first machine.

EDIT3: Removed all global npm packages, nothing. Here's the code:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Structure**

[image: structure]

Comment: Is there any error on the browser console?

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE   `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: change in *tsconfig.json* with es6 and re run  `"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",`

Comment: @pro.mean it threw a lot of similar errors: `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(17,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey' ...` This happened when both es6-shim was installed and when it was not. If that matters

Comment: will you show the code of `tsconfig.json` and `typings.json` files here

Comment: @pro.mean Updated. This has also been happening with other Angular2 repos as well

Comment: Can you also show your package.json?

Comment: @BjornSchijff Yeah

Comment: I had the same issue but it was the typo.. see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277205/angular2-quick-start-only-showing-loading-not-the-content-of-index-html)  may be helps you

Comment: @JackRothrock Thanks for adding the package.json, seems standard. Just to be sure, could you maybe screenshot your root folder structure? Maybe with the /app/ part opened up? 
You see nothing, not even the "Loading..." part?

Comment: @pro.mean, Yeah I thought it was too, but I got my exact same code above to work on a different machine - so idk

Comment: @BjornSchijff Yeah, nothing loads. When I check the page source it's just blank. I got the above code to work on a different machine, so idk

Comment: If that's the case, you may want to recheck your installation if the code runs fine on another machine. `npm purge` and `npm install` again to see if anything updates. Then try again?

Comment: @BjornSchijff No dice. I removed NPM, reinstalled it, and I'm still having the same issue - tried with multiple versions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for anyone else having this problem, the issue that I was having was that there was a dead process on the port. For those of you who are using a Mac. Check out this post:

[Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

check the filename of the files you have created manually , i did the same mistake here

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the case. This originally began when I was trying to use this github [repo](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted), got fed up with it, and tried doing it the manual way.

Comment: @JackRothrock i tried the folder structure  using the tutorial available here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/ . try creating the same , it has clear explanation of what to do and what not to do .

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work on a different machine following the same things as I did above, and with having the problems with the other repo, it leads me to believe it's something on this machine - what idk yet