# angular 2: working with a component's `this` in a Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

*UPDATE*
I've put a `return` after a console log and determined that the issue isn't the Promise -- it's reading that just fine. At the line I highlight in the code below, `this.contentItems = cpl.ary as ContentItem[];` is where the error is occuring. I've verified that `cpl` is an object with one property, `ary`, which is an array of 4 items. It displays in the console log fine. But when I try to get the `ary` property `as ContentItem[]` it comes up with `null` and tries to assign it to my empty `Content[]` on the left-hand side. So this is purely a casting or other type assignment issue. I'll change the subject of this question once I've found an answer.

My problem is that `this.contentItems` gets set to null in the `then` methods in content-display.component.ts.

The JSON I'm consuming is this:

```
{ "ary":[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Test Project",
    "nextDate": "2016-12-01T16:00:00",
    "dateDescription": "ends",
    "contentType": "project",
    "link": "http://google.com",
    "topics": ["1"]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Dummy Article",
    "nextDate": "2016-12-21T00:00:00",
    "dateDescription": "expires",
    "contentType": "article",
    "link": "http://msn.com",
    "topics": ["2"]
  }
]}
```

In my content-item.service.ts:

```
getContentItems(): Promise<ContentPayload> {
  if( window.location.hostname === "localhost" )
    return Promise.resolve( CONTENTITEMS );
  else
    return this.http.get( this.contentUrl )
                  .toPromise()
                  .then( (response) => { return response.json() } )
                  .then( (data) => { return data as ContentPayload })
                  .catch( this.handleError );
}
```

And back in my content-display.component.ts

```
private contentItems: ContentItem[] = [];

getContentItems(): void {
  this.contentItemService.getContentItems()
    .then( (contentPayload) => this.getArrayFromPayload )
    .then( this.getSelectOptions );
}

getArrayFromPayload( cpl: ContentPayload ): void {
  this.contentItems = cpl["ary"];
  /********** above, this.contentItems is set to null ************/
  this.filteredItems = this.contentItems;
}
```

ContentPayload:

```
export class ContentPayload {
  ary: any[];
}
```

ContentItem:

```
export class ContentItem {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  nextDate: Date;
  dateDescription: string;
  contentType: string;
  link: string;
  isClicked?: boolean = false;
  topics: string[];
}
```

This one is included for completeness. What it does isn't important, the error occurs above.

```
getSelectOptions( ): void {
  // return TOPICMAP;
  var topicMap: Topic[] = TOPICMAP;
  var filteredTopicMap: Topic[] = [];
  var uniqueValues: string[] = this.makeContentSet( this.getTopicIDs( this.contentItems ) );
  for( var i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++ ) {
    filteredTopicMap.push( this.getTopicWithID( topicMap, uniqueValues[i] ) );
  }
  this.selectOptions = filteredTopicMap;
}
```

And my template for this component (inconsistencies in style and use of "this" will be cleaned up eventually. And did you know iPads don't have back-ticks?):

```
template: `
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<div>Maximum of 20 items</div>
<div>Order:
  <span [class.clicked]="latestOldest==='latest'" (click)="mySort('latest')">latest first</span>
  |
  <span [class.clicked]="latestOldest==='oldest'" (click)="mySort('oldest');">oldest first</span>
</div>
<div>
  Filters:
  <ng-select
    [options] = "this.selectOptions"
    [multiple] = "this.showMultiple"
    placeholder = "Select topics"
    [allowClear] = "true"
    theme = "default"
    (selected) = "onSelected( $event )"
    (deselected) = "onDeselected( $event )">
  </ng-select>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let contentItem of filteredItems"
      (click)="onClick(contentItem)"
      class="{{contentItem.contentType}}"
      [class.clicked]="contentItem.isClicked">
    <h3>{{contentItem.name}}</h3>
    <div>{{ contentItem.contentType | uppercase }} {{ contentItem.dateDescription}}
      {{ contentItem.nextDate.toGMTString() | date:'mediumDate' }}
      {{ (contentItem.contentType !== "article")? (contentItem.nextDate | date:'shortTime'): '' }}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
`
```

Comment: I tried mocking out the http call with a mock ContentPayload object, but get the same result.

Comment: try changing ` .then( (contentPayload) => this.getArrayFromPayload )` to ` .then( this.getArrayFromPayload )`

Comment: thanks, but still getting 'EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'contentItems' of null'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36492169/uncaught-exception-in-promise-when-when-trying-to-use-nested-components  Looks like the template for your component might not be valid html. Show template?

Comment: You are missing a closing `</div>` for your open div on line 9

Comment: Thanks, bassxzero, I've fixed that, but that didn't help. See my update at the top of the post, it seems to be an error with the way I'm handling the payload. `cpl` appears as the JSON object, but `cpl.ary` doesn't find the array of `ContentItem[]`. The console, however, show that that value is [Object, Object, Object, Object], which should be correct.

Comment: Yeah I don't think `return data as ContentPayload` does what you want it to. Try explicitly creating and settings the properties of a `ContentPayLoad` instead of trying to cast a JSON object.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I think the problem in this particular case was that `this` in the function that was called in the Promise's `then` was not equivalent to the component. Not sure what it stood for, but something else. So I changed `.then( (contentPayload) => this.getArrayFromPayload )`, which assigned this.contentItems within that function, into `.then((contentPayload)=>this.contentItems = this.getArrayFromPayload)`, and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by not handling `this` correctly. There are many questions here on exactly this topic.

When you write the following

```
getContentItems(): void {
  this.contentItemService.getContentItems()
    .then( (contentPayload) => this.getArrayFromPayload )
    .then( this.getSelectOptions );
}
```

then you are basically pulling out the function of the object it was defined on (from the component instance in your case). The function still refers to some `this` but it won't get called with your component as `this` any more, that's what causes your problem.

The mentioned way in the comments of using `.then( this.getArrayFromPayload )` also doesn't work, as this also changes the context when the function is called.

There are several ways of fixing this. You could `bind()` the function passed to the `then` method to the this of the caller context like so

```
.then(this.getArrayFromPayload.bind(this))
```

Doing so sets the currently used `this` to the function such that it is preserved when the function is called. (It basically returns a new function that has the correct this reference)

Another way would be to use an arrow function which doesn't have an own `this` context and thus refers to the outer `this`.

```
getArrayFromPayload = (cpl: ContentPayload) => {
  this.contentItems = cpl["ary"];
  this.filteredItems = this.contentItems;
}
```

Doing so allows you to call it just like `.then( this.getArrayFromPayload )`.

For details on the underlying concepts, see this great answer covering the fundamentals of `this` in JavaScript: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485)